# How to apply kusto function to each rows?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am using kusto. I have a function and I want to use it for each row.
I can call the function with `| invoke <FUNCTION_NAME>`  but how can I apply to app rows ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the "extend" operator

For example:

```
let f = view(a:int){
a*3
};
let t = datatable(a:int) [ 1,2,3];
t 
| extend b = f(a)
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 9 |

Comment: thank you. this gives an extentation . however how can i do it, if I want to apply to data and yield a formated output

Comment: what do you mean by formatted output? can you give an example?

Comment: is it possible without extendeding it ?

Comment: yes, just name the column in the extend statement with the name of the original column, this means that the table schema will not change